# What are the downsides of removing ubuntu-desktop metapackage?

Tags: package-management

I once advised someone to remove a package that depends on **ubuntu-desktop** meta-package, if she didn't need it (EG: if one uses a different editor than **gedit**). Someone else said that doing so (removing **gedit** which will in turn remove **ubuntu-desktop**) could break things. Is this true? Are there any other potential problems?

Answer (score 5):

Removing the meta-package usually will not be a problem until you try to upgrade your system, but I would advise against it. Removing gedit and some of the other standard applications can also be problematic - if other programs depend on them. It is best that you leave them in place unless you know what you are doing. If you want to build your own minimal custom system, try [using](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/base/ubuntu-minimal) [ubuntu-minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Comment: When I remove something, I always get a display of what is going to get removed, so I think you are stressing __u must know what u r doing__ a bit too much. I also prefer pruning down instead of building up, so I can see exactly what functionality I'll be losing.

Comment: lawl - did you read my full answer?

Comment: huh? I did? wsup?

Comment: I specifically mentioned using ubuntu minimal and building something more minimal, and I only mentioned "u must know what r doing" as a precaution.

Answer (score 0):

During updates new dependencies of ubuntu-desktop will not be installed.

Comment: There aren't new dependencies during normal updates. When upgrading to a new version the update-manager checks for ubuntu-desktop (and x/kubuntu-desktop if you use that) and ensures it's installed.