# Why Ubuntu-Desktop package is allways associated with pulseaudio?

Tags: pulseaudio, system

As my question above, i wandered why ubuntu-desktop package is always with full association with pulseaudio packagae? Why can't we erase pulseaudio without erase ubuntu-desktop too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PA is an essential part of the Ubuntu desktop distribution.

However, you can safely remove the [meta-package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) `ubuntu-desktop` without losing any functionality, yet be aware that you won't receive any updates for that package (Which means you won't get new software which would have been pulled in by that package). See also [What are the downsides of removing ubuntu-desktop metapackage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21497/what-are-the-downsides-of-removing-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage)