# Replace notifyOSD with the XFCE version

Tags: notify-osd

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and I want to replace the notifyOSD with the XFCE version (I like how you can dismiss the notification).  I had a look in Synaptic and saw that there was a notifyosd-xfce but when I clicked install Syanptic wanted to remove the Gnome Desktop.

How do I add this without messing everything up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package name is `xfce4-notifyd` and it will only remove `notify-osd` (as they cannot co-exist) and the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. Latter one won't harm your system, but it has some downsides, see: [What are the downsides of removing ubuntu-desktop metapackage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21497/what-are-the-downsides-of-removing-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage)

That said: I don't know if `xfce4-notifyd` does what you want, but trying it won't hurt your system, as you can always go back by re-installing the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for the answer I think I will stick with the native  notifications.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 15.10, both notification daemon packages _can_ be installed at the same time, but `notify-osd` will _win_ and be in control of the notifications. So you'll have to remove it: `sudo apt-get remove notify-osd` and `sudo killall notify-osd` (or logout and login).