# How can I remove eog without breaking the Unity-2D session?

Tags: unity-2d, eog

On my Ubuntu 11.10 install, I want to use `gpicview` instead of `eog`. Therefore, I'd like to remove `eog`. Whenever I do `sudo apt-get remove eog` though, I'm notified that doing this will also remove `ubuntu-desktop`. But I want to keep using Unity 2D.

How can I remove `eog` while keeping the Unity-2D session?

Comment: Is there any harm in just keeping eog?

Comment: Well, not really harm. But it bothers me that image files are getting opened in `eog` which is slow, compared to `gpicview`. Of course, I can set every extension to be opened with `gpicview`, but removing `eog` would be far easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe ubuntu-desktop is a "metapackage" aka a package of packages. [MetaPackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages).
Thus when you un-install a package in that metapackage it un-installs the metapackage, but not the other packages in the metapackage, so removing eog and letting it un-install ubuntu-desktop should not harm Unity 2D, they made the ubuntu-desktop metapackage for ease of installing many programs and upgrading them all in one go. [what-are-the-downsides-of-removing-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21497/what-are-the-downsides-of-removing-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage)

Edit: [Is it safe to remove ubuntu-desktop package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126390/is-it-safe-to-remove-ubuntu-desktop-package) Seems distributions will still upgrade, because it forces install of desktop metapackage, and will still upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't remove eog, but it does make setting all pictures to open with gPicView easier.

1. Type Alt+F2 to get the run dialog, and then type `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`. Type in your password at the prompt.
2. Go to Search->Replace. Replace all instances of *eog* with *gpicview*. Close gedit.

That should set everything to use gPicView, and you can go on as if you had uninstalled eog, while still keeping the `ubuntu-desktop` package.