# Video player is freezing after using Dash to Dock GNOME extension in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, dock

Since I installed the GNOME extension Dash to Dock, the (default) video player is freezing when I click the close button or minimize button.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Also did you deactivate/uninstall the Ubuntu Dock extension before installing Dash to Dock? Since Ubuntu Dock is fork of Dash to Dock, running them at once is not a good idea, leads to various problems.

Comment: @pomsky when i uninstall this extension, there is no problem with video player.. i want to customize dock. so i tried gnome dash to dock..

Comment: What video player? Are you running 18.04 or 18.04.1? ie: are all of your Software Updates current?

Comment: all of my software is updated.. i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS .. talking about default video palyer. @heynnema

Comment: I also run with `Dash to Dock` without problems. Make sure you have the latest version v64. Go to `Videos` preferences, and turn off all plugins, and see if that helps. You can also try the `VLC` video player. It comes highly recommended. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Perhaps you're in a *vanilla* GNOME session instead of the Ubuntu-modified-GNOME one? Things are slightly complicated in the second one. Ubuntu Dock is a pre-installed system extension and it cannot be disabled using Tweaks or [from here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/). Then running Ubuntu Dock and Dash to Dock simultaneously leads to terrible glitches.

Comment: @pomsky How can I tell which GNOME session that I'm running? I believe that I'm running `GNOME on xorg`. Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu Appindicators are "mock" extensions, and are normally disabled. Dash to Dock is a superset of Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: @heynnema What are the outputs of `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`? In "GNOME on xorg" Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu Appindicators are disabled, but in the "Ubuntu" session, they cannot be (toggling ON/OFF in GNOME Tweaks doesn't have any effect, they always stay activated).

Comment: @pomsky the echo answers are `GNOME` and `ubuntu`.

Comment: @pomsky I just logged out to check which session I had selected, and it's set to `Ubuntu`. Is that wrong? What kinds of problems have you heard of with Dash to Dock?

Comment: @heynnema for example, this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975387/why-do-i-have-two-docks-in-ubuntu-17-10-desktop

Comment: @pomsky I've never seen a problem like that. The login screen session selector is set to `Ubuntu`. Is that the correct one to use for the "Ubuntu-modified-GNOME"?

Comment: @heynnema That's correct. By any chance is your system upgraded from an older release of Ubuntu GNOME distro instead of a fresh installation?

Comment: @pomsky yes, my system was an upgrade. Why is that significant?

Comment: @heynnema Perhaps that's why it's more GNOME-y than Ubuntu-ish :D