# Why are all the windows of an application getting minimized when I click on that app icon in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, minimize

When I try to minimize an application by clicking on its icon, it's minimizing all the windows of that application where I want only focused window to minimize.

Comment: *Hint:* as per your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080985/why-my-video-players-are-freezing-after-using-gnome-extension-in-ubuntu-18-04lt) you have installed the Dash to Dock extension which is causing this behaviour. Please always include *all* important details to avoid getting your question closed as unclear or having it remain unanswered.

Comment: actuall i did install only few extension. dash to dock and hide the top bar. i don't think it's have any relation with this.  i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS. @pomsky

Comment: And you're very likely wrong thinking there is no relation with this. Just because you have installed only a few extensions, **doesn't** mean they won't break things. As I [told you before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080985/why-my-video-players-are-freezing-after-using-gnome-extension-in-ubuntu-18-04lt#comment1776638_1080985), Ubuntu Dock is fork of Dash to Dock; they share many `gsettings` keys. Of course they would almost certainly affect each other.

Comment: @pomsky thanks for your quick reply. as you know ubuntu dock is a system exxtension. although dash to dock replace ubuntu dock. so should i uninstall ubuntu dock instead of disable this?

Comment: Disabling Ubuntu Dock is not easy as you've rightly pointed out it's a system extension and I won't recommend removing it, as it also removes the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage. You can do one thing, **install  but keep Dash to Dock deactivated** using GNOME Tweaks or something. Most, if not all, of the configurations you set for Dash to Dock should also be respected by the system dock because of shared `gsettings` keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(By default, Ubuntu Dock is not configured to minimize on click. For interested readers, please find how you can enable this behaviour below.)*

When you click on an app icon in Ubuntu Dock, which is configured to "minimize" if you click the icon, it would appear logical that the entire application is minimized by default. However, try pressing the **<kbd>Shift</kbd>** key while clicking an application icon. This will minimize only the most foremost window. Subsequent <kbd>Shift</kbd>+clicks will minimize the other windows one by one.

Having this behavior as the default option on clicking the icon of your focused application would be a feature request. You currently cannot configure Ubuntu Dock (and Dash to Dock) like this.

Such behavior might actually be considered to be inconsistent. After all, a click on an icon of a not focuses application currently raises *all* windows (as opposed to how Unity launcher works), so consistently, a single click should also hide *all* windows.

**Enabling the minimize on click and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click behaviour**

The quickest and safest way is to change the setting using`gsettings` terminal commands:

For click:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

For <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock shift-click-action 'minimize'
```

Alternatively, you can use `dconf-editor` (not installed by default), and navigate to that key to change the settings.