# 2 taskbars when I go to applications

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock

Whenever I go to the applications view I now see two separate taskbars. My Dash to Dock and some other one. Idk if it is Ubuntu dock, but when I went to GNOME Tweaks, that extension appeared to be off.

[image]

Is there a terminal command I could do to fix this. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have two docks in Ubuntu 17.10 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975387/why-do-i-have-two-docks-in-ubuntu-17-10-desktop) Do not use Dash to Dock along with Ubuntu Dock. Also you cannot easily disable Ubuntu Dock in a default Ubuntu session as it's a pre-installed system extension. It may say that Ubuntu Dock disabled in Tweaks, it's still active as you are experiencing.