# Disfunctionality of super key in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, activities-overview, dash-to-dock

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and super key not working properly.
When i enable dash to dock gnome extension, sometimes super key doesn't work and i have to reset gnome. When i press super key button to see activities for example.
Any idea?

UPDATE:
Sometimes another dock overlaying existing dock.[overlaying dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELYXj.png)

Comment: what happens when you try changing window action key to super in gnome tweaks?

Comment: Do you use any exotic keyboard layout? I have the same problem when I switch my keyboard to Hungarian layout.

Comment: It's already set to super.

Comment: I use Persian layout, but i have this problem in both English and Persian layouts.

Comment: By super do you mean the windows key?

Comment: Yes, the windows key.

Comment: **Do not** activate dash-to-dock without disabling the default Ubuntu Dock. The default one is fork of dash-to-dock, it may lead to various problems.  Does this answer your question? [Why do I have two docks in Ubuntu 17.10 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975387/why-do-i-have-two-docks-in-ubuntu-17-10-desktop)

Comment: About that overlaying dock, that's because of dash-to-dock extension issue. remove that to fix this. You can change dock like this:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-customize-dock-panel-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

But for me, on secondary (persian) keyboard layout, super key does not work either.

Comment: Similar issue. When I press the Super (Windows) key the search opens with a grey area on the right and nothing happens when clicking the found application other than everything else is disabled and I have to log out and in again to reset the usability of the desktop.

Comment: Alt-F, then 'r', and then Enter gets out of that without having to log out and back in.