# Two docks appearing after mac os customization

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, ubuntu-dock

I was customizing my ubuntu 20.04 to look like mac os catalina. I have followed normal protocols for customization including gnome-tweaks, dash to dock and blyr installation. So after the full customization, I had changed my dock to "bottom" position. However, now I am stuck with two docks. One is the original ubuntu dock, another is mac os dock (where the icons enlarge on hovering). Moreover, in the mac os dock, the icons are pixelated. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

[image: Image showing the two docks]

Already tried "Show all monitors" and "switch off ubuntu dock" processes. 
Actually, initially I had installed latte-dock for this mac os themed dock, after which I uninstalled latte dock but this os themed dock refuses to disappear.

Comment: Installing Dash to Dock over the pre-existing Ubuntu Dock is not a good idea as the second one is a fork of the previous. Also "switching off Ubuntu Dock" on a standard Ubuntu session is not so straightforward. Does this answer your question? [Why do I have two docks in Ubuntu 17.10 desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975387/why-do-i-have-two-docks-in-ubuntu-17-10-desktop)

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/q/1030138/480481

Answer (score 0):

I also have a problem like this... but I have two identical docks on top of each other!

[image: Image of weird ghosting]

Disabling the Gnome extension Dash to Dock fixes it, but loses the d2d changes I install it for!