# How to remove app icons in system tray on Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.04, top-bar

How can I remove the apps in right top corner (Google Chrome, flux, TeamViewer)?

[image: Top right corner on the System bar, between workspaces and keyboard language in this picture]

Before my update from Ubuntu GNOME 16 these were even more annoying in the left down corner.

Comment: You probably have an extension that enables them active, try checking out gnome tweaks and seeing what you have active.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those icons are provided by a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called **Ubuntu appindicators** (package name: `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`). Since it's a system extension, it may not be easy to simply disable it using *GNOME Tweaks* or from [the GNOME Shell Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/).

For newer Ubuntu releases you can use the following command to disable the extension:

```
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
```

Note that removing the `gnome-shell-extension-appindicator` package would get rid of those icons,  **but it is not at all recommended** as it will also remove the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package which may break stuff in future (see this: [Is it safe to remove ubuntu-desktop package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126390/480481)).

**1. Hackish solution with granular control**

You may use another [extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[**Icon Hider**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/)" to achieve your goal. This extension lets you toggle the visibility of individual icons in top-bar.

After installing and activating the extension, open its settings. You should find entries corresponding to those icons you want to hide towards the bottom (for example in the screenshot below I have entries corresponding to "Skype" and "Alarm Clock" applications). Just toggle them off.
(You may have to re-login to see the effect.)

[image]

**2. Alternative solution**

Another solution is to [use vanilla GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964598/how-do-i-get-a-vanilla-gnome-after-ubuntu-17-04) (GNOME shell sans modifications made by Ubuntu). Since GNOME got rid of the legacy tray (the old annoying tray at the bottom-left corner) from version 3.26, those icons in top-bar are disabled by default.

You may install vanilla GNOME by running

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

Once it is installed, reboot (or re-login). Once you get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find options titled "*GNOME*" and "*GNOME on Wayland*" along with *Ubuntu* and *Ubuntu on Wayland*. Select any of the *GNOME* options instead of *Ubuntu* options.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution will be making a backup of the file responsible for showing app indicators.
Simply change this...
`/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js`
to this
`/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js.BAK`
And don't forget to restart the machine/session for changes to take effect ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gnome tweaks then disable the extensions and add ons only select which you wanted or can download gnome tweaks from ubuntu software
and resolve it from there