# How can I hide redundant icon on task bar?

Tags: icons, panel, system-tray, 23.04, gnome-dash

I am using xpad with dash to panel, and xpad icon is redundant: there is a tray icon on the right and whenever a new note is open, it also appears on running apps.
I understand this is not a bug but the proper way of functioning, since it is nothing strange that running apps are present.
I know that there's an option to hide all running apps from dash to panel, but that is not suitable for me: I'd only like to remove this redundancy.
Is it possible to hide specific running apps from the taskbar? (I prefer the tray one).
Thank you very much

[image: caption to show the issue]

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster

Comment: Not tried this personally but you could explore this solution - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027890/how-to-remove-app-icons-in-system-tray-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-gnome

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try.