# How can I get rid of the Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension

[image: screenshot with Ask Ubuntu open in Firefox, dock on left]

The big dock on the left. In other versions you could escape Unity Launcher by going to GNOME, what now? GNOME tweaks is not showing it as an extension, even though it looks a lot like Dash to Dock.

[image: Tweaks/Extensions dialog]

I see autohide options in settings, but no way to completely remove it and use the GNOME default.

Edit: I'm **not** looking for vanilla GNOME, but simply to hide the dock.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Run the following:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
sudo mv ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com{,.bak}
```

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` in the input.

---

In case if you need to undo:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
sudo mv ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com{.bak,}
```

Comment: This is a nice way to go if you don't want to remove any software, i.e. you want to go back and use the vanilla dock some time in the future.

Comment: Is the folder re-created when the ubuntu-dock package gets upgraded via apt?

Comment: How to bring it back?

Comment: How to bring the dock back?

Answer (score 26):

Since Ubuntu Dock is a system extension (package name: [`gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/)), it is not possible to simply disable it using *GNOME Tweaks* or from the [GNOME Shell Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/).

Removing this package by running

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

should get rid of the dock,  **but it is not recommended** as it will also remove the [`ubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-desktop) meta-package which *may* break stuff later (see this: [Is it safe to remove ubuntu-desktop package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126390/480481)).

Arguably a cleaner solution is to use [vanilla GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/q/964598/480481) (GNOME shell sans modifications made by Ubuntu). In vanilla GNOME, Ubuntu Dock disabled by default.

You may install vanilla GNOME by running

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

Once it is installed, reboot (or re-login). Once you get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find options titled "*GNOME*" and "*GNOME on Wayland*" along with *Ubuntu* and *Ubuntu on Wayland*. Select any of the *GNOME* options instead of *Ubuntu* options.

Answer (score 17):

#### For Ubuntu 20.04

The dock is listed as a built in extension. You can simply go to the built in app "Extensions" and then disable the dock.

Answer (score 12):

It can be also disabled without hacking system files, or removing packages and breaking dependencies.

Using old `gnome-shell-extension-tool`:

```bsh
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Or, via new `gnome-extensions`:

```bsh
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

In the end, these commands should store configuration in dconf, where `dconf dump /` outputs something like:

```
...

[org/gnome/shell]
disabled-extensions=['desktop-icons@csoriano', 'ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com']
enabled-extensions=['system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com']

...
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 running `gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` worked for me. Thanks! And I guess since it is the system extension, it is the easiest way to disable it without breaking something.

Comment: You most probably meant `gnome-shell-extension-tool` **`-d`** `ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` instead. But even `gnome-shell-extension-tool -d ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` doesn't hide the dock on my standard Ubuntu 18.04 installation. It just toggles the enabled/disabled status for the extension (as seen in GNOME Tweaks, just as in the screenshot in the question), but has no effect on the actual visibility of the dock itself.

Comment: In 20.04 `gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` does the trick, no the version with `-d` in the comment above.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:** If you want to remove it completely delete the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` (make backup in case of emergency). Then restart.

#### If you want to tweak more use dconf-editor:

You can tweak the dock from **dconf-editor**. Install it by `sudo apt install dconf-tools`.

Open dconf-editor and goto `org->gnome->shell->extension->dash-to-dock`. You can do some tweaks like hiding dock, turn off extending dock etc.
[image: dconf-editor]

Comment: "hiding dock" is not possible, is it?

Comment: @pomsky yes it is not possible via dconf-editor. But if it is needed to remove completely , delete  `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` folder and restart.

Comment: Not a permanent solution, since the package is a part of `ubuntu-desktop` metpackage, it will get reinstalled every now and then.