# How can I replace default Ubuntu Dock with Dash To Dock gnome extension?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

The problem is, that Ubuntu Dock extension looks like "disabled" in GNOME TWEAK TOOL, so it is impossible to disable it that way. After I installed Dash To Dock extension, both docks shows up in "dash view" mode. How can I disable Gnome Dock and why it is not possible to disable it using GNOME TWEAK TOOL same way as any other gnome extensions can be disabled ?

Comment: What happens if you visit [https://extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org)? You should be able to disable the extension from its own web page.

Comment: @Jos It's not possible. As Ubuntu Dock is a system extension, it's can't be activated/deactivated using the webpage or GNOME Tweaks in the default Ubuntu session(s).

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a duplicate. I try installing Dash-to-dock but then I started to see a double dock, specially with the Activities overview. The only way to truly fix this is by also uninstall `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`.
Too bad I can't add this as an answer since other people might stumble upon this question without a proper answer

Comment: @Felipe You can post that answer to the to one of the target questions without an issue: https://askubuntu.com/q/1030138/480481. That's what duplicates are for -- to work as a signpost to direct future readers to the correct place to look for answers. That said, if you remove `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` package, then `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage would also get removed. That may break stuffs, so proceed with caution.

Comment: @pomsky The problem is that this question is not really a duplicate of the one marked there. The original deals with how to remove Ubuntu dock. This question is related to a bug that shows both docks, and the answer could be something completely different than just removing Ubuntu dock. It just happens to be that it is, but that's definitely not apparent from marking this a duplicate of the other one. So posting my answer on the original would make no sense. As an alternative, I've posted an answer here, where is relevant an appropriate: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/739

Comment: @Felipe Why not? I found your answer really good and suitable for the other question too (maybe just add the potential consequence(s) of removing `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage also as a warning and full disclaimer). I would request you to post your answer to that question (ping me if you do).