# Dock moves to left side resulting in double dock when clicking "Show Applications"

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock, gnome-tweak-tool

I've installed dash to dock days ago and somehow I noticed that after using it for a while, when I click "Show Applications" it'll create a dock on the left side (which is functioning) but disappears when existing "Shows Application".

**My Original Dock**
[image]

**Show Applications**
[image]

> **(Update) The ubuntu dock is turned off**
>   [image]

My temporary solution is to change the dock to the left side and change it back to the bottom, but still it comes back every while.
How can I fix this?

Comment: It's a bad idea to run Dash to Dock along with the default Ubuntu Dock.

Comment: @PRATAP 18.04 and the `ubuntu-dock` is turned off

Comment: @PRATAP thanks, Ill give it a try and observe for a while

Comment: Just turning off Ubuntu Dock in Tweaks would most probably won't be good enough as it's a pre-installed system package, refer to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1030138/480481

Comment: @pomsky Thanks, seems like I will have to leave it there just as it is