# How to "always-hide" dock in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, ubuntu-dock, dock, gnome-dash

In Ubuntu 19.10 there's automatically converted GNOME's dash to dock. And, configuration:

- "settings -> dock": offers only option "Auto-hide the Dock",
- "GNOME Tweaks": can't configure any extension about dock.

However, I need to hide it always, except when activity/search menu/screen is shown. As, it's pretty much annoying slowdown, when I want to press some button on the left side, and dock shows and covers application's buttons,...

Comment: You just need to get rid of the Ubuntu Dock. The "dock" in '*Activities*' overview (viz. GNOME Dash), is an in-built feature of GNOME Shell. So it would be available anyway. Does this answer your question? [How can I get rid of the dock in Ubuntu 18?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030138/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-dock-in-ubuntu-18)

Comment: @pomsky, yes, though,.. disabled is enough, instead of "get rid",..

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple way to *disable* it, since it's pre-installed system extension that is always activated by default in an Ubuntu session.

Comment: @pomsky Well,.. there is quite simple way (in the end, it's one-liner, though needs a bit of research). I have just shared the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1217515/1841

Comment: Hmm... it didn't seem to work on a standard Ubuntu session on Ubuntu 18.04. Looks like there is no 'disabled-extensions' key at `org/gnome/shell` (there is the 'enabled-extensions' one though).