# How can I remove Tilda?

Tags: uninstall, ubuntu-mate, tilda

I installed Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 the other day and have it completely configured perfectly for my needs with one exception.  I really do not use nor want Tilda.  When I tried to remove it today, I was met with this message:

```
╔═◯ ~                                                                             
╚═▷ arm tilda [* I used Fish and 'arm' is aliased to 'apt remove', btw]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tilda ubuntu-mate-core ubuntu-mate-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 433 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I do **not** want to proceed for obvious reasons.

Can anyone give me a hand here?  Am I stuck with Tilda?  Is there another way to remove it?

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu MATE for a month and didn't even noticed it's got Tilda... Don't see how that can disturb your normal workflow. You don't have to use it. Or maybe you simply want to have different usage for F12?

Comment: That would probably be a good solution.  Dont know why I hadn't thought of changing the keyboard shortcut.  Thanks.
(Making it a keystroke combination nobody in their right mind wouold ever, ever do, helps significantly!)

Answer (score 1):

Open *System -> Preferences -> Personal -> Startup Applications* (or run `mate-session-properties`) and there's actually "Tilda" there, just waiting to be disabled xD

[image]

It surely gives that extra ~40MB of free RAM and unnoticably speeds-up boot!

If it's just a matter of keyboard shourtcuts, Tilda got nice preferences for everything.

Answer (score 0):

`ubuntu-mate-core` and `ubuntu-mate-desktop` are both metapackages. They are lists of packages and not actual packages themselves.

Look at the output of `apt show ubuntu-mate-core | grep Section` and `apt-show ubuntu-mate-desktop | grep Section`. Both contain `Section: universe/metapackages`

You could next confirm that, other than `tilda` and the two metapackages, no other "real" package will be removed by running:

`apt remove -s tilda`

which will only simulate a removal because of -`s`.

You can read more about metapackages and the consequences of removing them here: [What are the downsides of removing ubuntu-desktop metapackage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21497/what-are-the-downsides-of-removing-ubuntu-desktop-metapackage)